# is "P" of Photon: 《equal to E×(1/c) OR E×(1/v)》 AND 《inversely proportion to its velocity?》

Tags: energy, photons, momentum, velocity

We know that
$$ E^2=(mc^2)^2 + (pc)^2 \;,$$
and in the case of photon $m=0$, so
$$ E=pc $$
OR
$$ p=E/c \;.$$

Can we say that:

- momentum of photon is equal to the product of its Energy and the inverse of its velocity OR velocity of light?
- momentum of photon is inversely proportional to its velocity OR velocity of light?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. This is a great site for physics questions and answers, but note that we have rules/guidelines to make sure the quality is high. One of our guidelines is that you should type your question instead of using an image. This is important because 1) Images are harder to read, 2) Images cannot be searched, 3) Images cannot be edited by others. Please spend some time looking around the site at other questions with positive votes so that you can see what a good question looks like. Also, please see how to use [mathjax](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Related: In special relativity $||(Ec^{-2},m\partial_t \mathbf{x}\partial_\tau t)||_{\eta}$ is invariant ($-(mc)^2$) (or something). (This might be wrong on the c's, just wanted to give context)

Comment: Click the link where it says "edited [some time ago]" to see how others have edited you content. The main rendering engine here is markdown, which is faster and less error prone than html, and with the MathJax engine running you can have nicely typeset equations.

Comment: @dmckee i'll try to learn

Answer (score 0):

The velocity of the photon is c.  So for question a it is one in the same.

For b, there is an understanding issue.  c is constant and P is not.  You have removed the only variable from the right side of the equation.  You can say that there is a proportionality between p and E but not p to a constant.

Comment: hey bro! i didnt get you, could you please explain me a little bit?

Comment: do you mean that i should say that, p is jointly proportional to E/c if you are trying to explain this then, i would add that i just broke the equation and i can say that p is inversely proportional to c, without including E, it doesn't matter!

Comment: It *does* matter. The speed of light is a constant, so every photon uses *the same* $c$. But photon energies vary and every photon does *not* use the same $E$. The only physically interesting statement you can make about the expression $E = pc$ is that energy and momentum are proportional to one another, because $c$ is playing the role of a constant of proportionality.

Comment: When I write down a proportionality it is a statement that as the left side varies, the right side varies.  i.e. if is say $a$ is proportional to $b$ then with all other things being constant, if $a$ doubles, I expect $b$ to double.  Here we have $p$ is proportional to $1/c$.   So if $p$ doubles $1/c$ should??????  Nothing because it is constant.  This is a nonsensical statement.